# Python - finding all paths between points of arbitrary shape

Tags: python, generator, nodes, graph-theory

My goal for the program is the following:

Given *any shape* (represented as enumerated points and their connections to other points), return a *list* containg *all possible paths* (as strings/lists/...). A path is a 'drawing' of the given shape, in which:

no connection has been used *more than once* and

the 'pen' hasn't been lifted (example included below).

[image: animation of a house being drawn as described above]

The following code is essentially what I've come up with so far. It's not the code of the actual program, but the basic semantics are the same (i.e. if this code will work, my program will work too).

```
"""
Example used:

    2
   / \
  /   \
 /     \
1-------3
"""


from copy import deepcopy

points = {1: [2,3],
          2: [1,3],
          3: [1,2]}

def find_paths(prev_point, points):
    for current_point in points[prev_point]:
        points[current_point].remove(prev_point)
        points[prev_point].remove(current_point)
        return [prev_point] + find_paths(current_point, points)
    return [prev_point]

def collect(points):
    results = []
    for first_point in points:
        result = find_paths(first_point, deepcopy(points))
        results.append(result)
    return results

print(collect(points))
```

**My struggle has been to make it return *all* paths.** As of now, it lists only 3 (out of 6). I do understand that the issue arises from the `for`-loop in `f` being executed exactly once each time it is called (and it's being called 3 times), since the execution is terminated by `return` each time. However, I have up until now failed to find a way to avoid this - I played around with making `f` a generator but this has given me a list of generators as the end result, no matter how I tried to change it.

*Any help is appreciated!*

EDIT: The generator-version I had simply replaced the `return`s in `find_paths`  with `yield` s.
So the last two lines look like:

`...
    yield [prev_point] + find_paths(current_point, points)
yield [prev_point]`

Additionally, I played around with a 'flattener' for generators, but it didn't work at all:

`def flatten(x):
    if callable(x):
        for i in x:
            yield flatten(i)
    yield x`

def func():
    yield 1
lis = [1,2,func]

for f in flatten(lis):
    print(f)

Comment: If this isn't for homework are you sure there isn't a library out there to do this already? If it is homework then good job actually providing what you've done so far and giving a better question than "can you do this for me".

Comment: `for current_point in points[prev_point]:... points[prev_point].remove(current_point)` Do not remove from something while you iterate over it. I suggest making a copy: `for current_point in points[prev_point][:]`. Secondly your idea with generators sounds good, show us the code for that and we'll tell you how to fix it instead. But first try simply converting the generator to a list, that's easy.

Comment: One problem I see is you have no "end condition" for your recursive `find_paths` function. You need to know when to stop. Also your find_paths has no way of returning "multiple paths" which is what it seems is expected.

Comment: @daveydave400 Tbh I haven't looked for a library because I wanted to do this as a free-time project myself (not for school ;) ) Also, I think you mean the <code>return [prev_point]</code>, which runs if the <code>points </code> dictionary is 'empty'.

Comment: If you're looking around for information on this problem, it looks like a variation on the Seven Bridges of Königsberg

Comment: You are looking to generate "Euler Walks" or "Eulerian Path" of the graph that your shape is a representation of

Comment: @Alex-Hall I'm not sure what you mean by turning the generator into a list... Could you provide some example code, please? And I will edit it just now to add the generator version.

Comment: @Michael `list(gen)`, this will turn those generator objects in to lists so you can use/view them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the following works. I based it off of your original code, but did a few things (some necessary, some not):

1. Rename parameters in `find_paths` to make more sense for me. We are working with the `current_point` not the `previous_point`, etc.
2. Add an end condition to stop recursion.
3. Make a copy of points for every possible path being generated and return (yield) each one of those possible paths. Your original code didn't have logic for this since it only expected one result per call to `find_paths`, but that doesn't really make sense when using recursion like this. I also `extend` my final result for the same reason.

Here is the code:

```
from copy import deepcopy

points = {1: [2,3],
          2: [1,3],
          3: [1,2]}


def find_paths(current_point, points):
    if len(points[current_point]) == 0:
        # End condition: have we found a complete path? Then yield
        if all(not v for v in points.values()):
            yield [current_point]
    else:
        for next_point in points[current_point]:
            new_points = deepcopy(points)
            new_points[current_point].remove(next_point)
            new_points[next_point].remove(current_point)
            paths = find_paths(next_point, new_points)
            for path in paths:
                yield [current_point] + path


def collect(points):
    results = []
    for first_point in points:
        result = find_paths(first_point, points)
        results.extend(list(result))
    return results

print(collect(points))
```

Results in:

```
[1, 2, 3, 1]
[1, 3, 2, 1]
[2, 1, 3, 2]
[2, 3, 1, 2]
[3, 1, 2, 3]
[3, 2, 1, 3]
```

Your original example image should work with the following:

```
points = {
    1: [2,3],
    2: [1,3,4,5],
    3: [1,2,4,5],
    4: [2,3,5],
    5: [2,3,4],
    }
```

**Edit:** Removed the extra deepcopy I had in `collect`.

It is necessary to copy the `points` every time because you are "saving" the current state of the current path you are "drawing". If you didn't copy it then going down the path to node 2 would change the state of the points when going down the path to node 3.

Comment: Thanks a lot!! Why is it necessary to deepcopy the original <code>points </code> though? I wouldn't have expected this to work at all to be quite frank

Comment: It probably isn't, just an artifact of copying your code....Edit: fixed